# How do I get a counter to work within a discord.py command function?

Tags: python-3.6, discord, discord.py

How do I get a counter to increase within a command function? For example:

```
global counter
counter = 0
@client.command(pass_context=True)
   async def pick(ctx):
   counter += 1
```

Every time I try to do this, it gives me this error: 
**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment**
I have tried so many ways to get this to work but I can not figure it out to save my life as well as my loved ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to acomplish what you want.

For one you can, as mentioned in hopethatsacleanwet's answer, just global the variable name so you can access the one in the global scope and not the local scope.

```
@client.command()
async def pick():
    global counter
    counter += 1
```

you also could, as mentioned in benjin's answer, use a cog to bind the variable to a scope the function has access to.

```
class MyCog:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.counter = 0

    @commands.command()
    async def pick(self):
        self.counter += 1

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
```

you could even bind the counter to the bot

```
client.counter = 0
@client.command()
async def pick():
    bot.counter += 1
```

I reccomend you read up on [python's namespaces](https://www.python-course.eu/namespaces.php)

Comment: The last one worked for me just fine. Thank you, I will read up on the hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a cog with a class and using `self.counter`. You do this by creating a separate file that contains the Class, creating a `setup` function at the bottom, and then using `load_extension` in your main code where you run the bot. Example code below.

**bot.py**

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

client.load_extension('cog')

client.run('TOKEN')
```

**cog.py**

```
from discord.ext import commands

class TestCog:

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.counter = 0

    @commands.command()
    async def pick(self):
        self.counter += 1
        await self.bot.say('Counter is now %d' % self.counter)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(TestCog(bot))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that error is occurring is because Python is trying to define `counter` in a local scope within the `pick` command. In order to access the global variable you need to "redefine" it as global in the local context. Changing the `pick` command to this will fix it:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def pick(ctx):
    global counter
    counter += 1
```